# How to use aloha editor on the website

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use aloha editor on my website and i downloaded it from [http://aloha-editor.org/].Now i am totally confused because the downloaded bundle contain lots of files.

I pick up aloha.js and aloha.css and added the following script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      Aloha.ready(function () {
          var $ = Aloha.jQuery;
          $('.editable').aloha();
      })
});
```

but its not working.Then i tried

```
<script src="http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/current/lib/aloha.js"
      data-aloha-plugins="common/format,
      common/list,
      common/link,
      common/highlighteditables">
</script>

<!-- load the Aloha Editor CSS styles -->
<link href="http://cdn.aloha-editor.org/current/css/aloha.css" type="text/css" />

<!-- make all elements with class="editable" editable with Aloha Editor -->
<script type="text/javascript">
     Aloha.ready( function() {
            var $ = Aloha.jQuery;
            $('.editable').aloha();
     });
</script>
```

It works fine. But i want to use my downloaded bundle, Can anyone tell me how can i manage all the files & folders (for ex- where i have to put image folder and other folder..) so it starts working?

Comment: IMO, aloha is a little messy, so it expects you to put /plugin, /lib, /img folders at the root directory. Some of the directory structures are even hard coded inside aloha.js & aloha.css, so your best bet is to dig into the code, and hack it till you are happy. Another plugin that may be less messy but quite basic is Hallo JS

Comment: How are you including Aloha's source and plugins from your site and what errors are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Copy all the files in to the root directory which includes plugins,lib,img,css and refer above described guide.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.alohaeditor.org/guides/using_aloha.html.
Save the files in `/javascripts` in the root directory of your web server, such as where localhost is run.